# symfony 3.3.2 sensio/generator-bundle is abandoned

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose, composer-php

Hey i have problem with symfony project
i install all my packages from docker compose
the problem is the some Packages is abandoned
and i can't to build the whole project
Errors from docker log
Package sensio/distribution-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested
Package sensio/distribution-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested
Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
2020-10-27T16:20:59.073773504Z PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap() must be an instance of Composer\Script\CommandEvent, instance of Composer\Script\Event given, called in phar:///var/www/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php on line 323 and defined in /var/www/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:33
2020-10-27T16:20:59.073777787Z
and then this not create all directories like app/log app/cache

Comment: What's your question? How is this related to Docker?

Comment: i build the project via docker compose 
the problem when i run php composer.phar install 
i get error 
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap() must be an instance of Composer\Script\CommandEvent, instance of Composer\Script\Event given, called in phar:///var/www/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php

Comment: Please add all relevant information to your question, also containing a question. Is there anything we could help you with?

Comment: i add all info i can give 
the error msg and 
i will update my question and add the composer.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello the right problem is  `Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap() must be an instance of Composer\Script\CommandEvent, instance of Composer\Script\Event given`.

It commes with composer 2 that not give same arguments for composer scripts.

To avoid this error you must update the version of `sensio/distribution-bundle`
with at least the version `3.0` since it the first version with the right composer argument [code](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/3.0/Composer/ScriptHandler.php#L67)

Comment: i change the version to v3.0.0 and i get same error
and i run in the container rm -rf vendor rm -rf bin  php composer.phar clearcache

php composer.phar install php composer.phar update

Comment: Maybe try with an other higher version 5.0.0 ?

Comment: the problem is this 
Package sensio/distribution-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested